# Linux Mint 18.2 second monitor not working (works with lowered resolution)

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, graphics, multi-monitor, amd-graphics

I'm running two ASUS VE247H monitors, graphics card AMD Radeon R9 380. Both monitors are connected using DVI cables. I have dual boot configured with windows 10 and linux mint 18.2 cinnamon 64bit. They work flawlessly on windows 10, however on linux the second monitor continuously turns on and off and for some reason when I adjust the second monitor's resolution from 1920x1080 to 1680x1050, it works.

I've also tried installing drivers manually from https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/Radeon-Software-for-Linux-Release-Notes.aspx (downloading Radeon™ Software for Linux® version 18.20 for Ubuntu 16.04.4), however it did not solve the issue. Instead it broke my distribution, on boot I would be stuck in what seems to be a command line (flashing underscore for typing), however it did not register any key strokes. I fixed it by uninstalling the driver in recovery mode.